# Failed to retrieve this workspace error when attempting to launch Azure Synapse Studio

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am trying to do some testing with Azure Synapse Studio. I setup an Azure Synapse Workspace, but when I click the "Launch Synapse Studio" link, it quickly throws an error and then the screen goes white. I took a screenshot of the error before it went away and it says "Workspace is not..." for the header and "Failed to retrieve this workspace." Am I doing something wrong? [image]

Comment: Based on my experience, you can try the following methods.

Comment: 1. You can try to recreate it. The name does not contain special characters, only English letters.

Comment: 2. When trying to create, select another region.

Comment: 3. If it is not possible, you can raise a ticket on the portal and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to have to recreate it, so went with Jason Pan's option 3 listed in the comments. Support was quick to help and my issue was escalated a couple of levels. They ended up making a configuration change on the back-end that fixed the problem.